# Can a HTML Canvas use multiple fillStyles to draw different colours?

Tags: html, canvas

Using a single canvas, I have drawn five boxes, but when I fill them, only the final fillStyle is applied to all the boxes, despite the others having been assigned fillStyles.

e.g:

```
//Create AnswerBox 2
var context2 = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
context2.rect(500, 410, 800, 100);
context2.fillStyle = "#bdff00";
context2.fill();

//Create AnswerBox 3
var context3 = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
context3.rect(500, 520, 800, 100);
context3.fillStyle = "#f0ff00";
context3.fill();

//Create AnswerBox 4
var context4 = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
context4.rect(500, 630, 800, 100);
context4.fillStyle = "#ff6600";
context4.fill();

//Create AnswerBox 5
var context5 = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
context5.rect(500, 740, 800, 100);
context5.fillStyle = "#ec1a1a";
context5.fill();
```

Does this mean that a canvas can only draw with one fillStyle and I would need to use five smaller canvases to have five differently coloured boxes?

Comment: The main issue is that you aren't using beginPath() before defining a new rect(). The last fill will therefor fill all the previous rects as well with the last defined fillStyle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Does this mean that a canvas can only draw with one fillStyle...???***

nope, you can set/changr the fillStyle as much as you want/need, where the new value apply only to the object you draw at that point....

dont create context objets from the same canvas, reeuse it instead:

## Example:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 30, 30);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx.fillRect(70, 70, 30, 30);
```

the following code will produce multiple rects wit different styles:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the correction, you're right I should use the same context object.

I have edited my code to reflect this, however my problem still remains of only the final fillStyle being applied to all five boxes

Comment: See the [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/3241/path-syntax-only/11126/beginpath-a-path-command#t=201702041722225948606) on `beginPath`